# Java - Cannot Find Symbol Error With Other Classes

Tags: java, class, cannot-find-symbol

First and foremost I want to make myself clear: ***I am not asking what the*** `cannot find symbol` ***error means, I am simply asking what is causing this error in this context.***

I have recently delved into classes in Java. Below is my first [non `main`] class:

```
class Test {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
exit status 1
Main.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                test();
                ^
  symbol:   method test()
  location: class Main
1 error
```

Can anyone please explain why this happens?

`System.out.println("Thanks!");`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method test() is not declared static.

You are calling a non-static method test() in a static method main(). If you do not want to change the class Test you have to change main() as follow

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.test();
}
```

If you do not want to change main() too much. Then you have to change the test() method as follow:
    public static void test() {}

and the inside the main() method:

```
Test.test()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `test()` method in Main class. Because `test()` method defined in another class, in Test class. To reach `test()` method in other class (Main class), you have to create an object and you can reach `test()` method through this object. `test()` method is an instance method which belongs to Test class.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test test1 = new Test();
      test1.test();
  }
}
```